# Is there some general technique to turn the operation of function into a continuous transformation from input to output?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

To be precise:

Given a function $f(x)$ I want a function $g(t, x)$, $x,t \in \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, such that $g(t, x)$ equals the $t$-time application of $f$ to the value $x$ for $t \in \mathbb{N}$,

This means, $g(0, x) = x, g(1, x) = f(x), g(2, x) = f(f(x))$, and g should be continuous in $t$.

It feels like I want something like an "analytic continuation", like the gamma function extending the discrete factorial function into a smooth transformation. Is there some algorithm that can be applied to get some kind of taylor expansion or even a closed form systematically?

For example,

- if $f(x) = x+c$, then I want $g(t, x) = x+ct$
- if $f(x) = ax$, then $g(t, x) = a^t x$
- if $f(x) = ax+b$, then $g(t, x) = a^t x + \frac{b(a^t-1)}{a-1}$

the last one I managed to figure out the closed form for, but e.g. for $f(x) = x^2 + c$ the iterated function explodes into increasingly higher degree polynomials that I don't know how to handle.

My formal understanding of calculus is on the level of standard university courses, so if this goes way way deeper, please be gentle!

Comment: $g$ is the iterated function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function

Comment: Unfortunately, this does go way deeper than calculus. fix $x$, which is irrelevant at this point. The recursion defines $g$ for integer values of $t$ only. Now choose **any** continuous function $h$ defined on $[0,1]$ with $h(0) = x, h(1) = f(x)$. and define $g(t,x) = h(t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$. The recursion then extends $g$ to a continuous function for all $t$. But a different function for each $h$ you pick. This over-abundance of choices for $g$ remains even if you require $g$ to be infinitely differentiable. To get a "best" choice, you need to require that $g$ be *analytic*.

Comment: (cont) That means $g$ can be represented by a power series about each point $t$. Complex analysis has tools for building analytic functions from a sequence of points such as $g(n, x)$, but I'm rusty on the results, and will leave a fuller explanation to others.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I should have stumbled onto the wiki page myself, apparently what I want is a "fractional iterate" or "flow". Okay so I guess its a much deeper rabbit hole than I thought. I was just hoping that this could be used to "interpolate" smooth trajectories for e.g. tracking the orbit of a point acted on by a dynamical system. Then I'll probably just use something spline-like, even though it's not showing the "correct" path...